# Flex mobile app crashes/hangs while waiting for web service response

Tags: android, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I have having problems with a WSDL/SOAP service call in an app I have built in flash builder for mobile. I have connected to the service using flash builders built in data/services functionality.

For the most part, the service call works perfectly but once in a while it will cause the app to crash - on my android device it completely locks up (spinning animation stops) and then Android informs me that the app is not responding and asks if I want to close it.

The crash appears to occur quite frequently but not with any pattern. One time it happened on my third attempt, another time it took approximately 30, a couple of times I could not get it to happen and most times it occurs somewhere in between.

It appears that the crash happens after a service call is made but before any response is received. Neither the success or the fault listeners are ever fired. I am very confident that I am sending exactly the same variables to the service every time.

I have used web service calls in other apps without trouble so I have to assume there is something in this particular build that is causing problems but I can't seem to find anything.

Any thoughts on possible causes, things to test or even a solution would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you,

Jamie

Comment: You need to include the error message and the code snip from where it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks essential details, so now I can suggest you to setup `Charles` proxy and monitor you requests trough it.

If you send too many requests simultaneously, you shall not be confident in fault/result events as air runtime has limitations (in any case, it is a good practice to handle request timeout).